# how to represent date type in apache thrift

Tags: date, types, thrift

I'm developing a service using [apache thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and I need to define periods of time. Dates are significant (`YYYY-mm-dd`) and time should be totally omitted (`HH:ii:ss`). I couldn't find any specific date/datetime thrift data type so I'm thinking about two approaches:

1. more complex

   ```
   int year,
   int month,
   int day,
   ```
2. less complex but includes time of day part which I don't need.

   ```
   int timestamp
   ```

Is there a common thrift approach to represent date(time) types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a date representation on Thrift IDL. We use this notation for our projects.

```
typedef string Timestamp
```

then use that notation on subsequent model which needs a timestamp usage like this

```
struct blah{

    /**
    * TODO:list what notation this dateTime represents. eg ISO-8601
    * or if its in the format like YYYY-mm-DD you mentioned.
    */
    1:Timestamp dateTime;

    }
```

String makes it easier to use [JODA Operations](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

--EDIT--

I don't know what timestamp you intend to store. For instance if you want to calculate current instance a transaction has occurred and store it into that thrift object, you can do this with Joda.

```
    String timestamp = new DateTime().toString("YYYY-MM-dd"); //2013-03-26 This will be string value generated. It will convert the current time to format you seek to output.
    //Use the generated thrift object.
    Blah newblah = new Blah();
    blah.setDateTime(timestamp);
```

Comment: Haven't heard about JODA, but it seems promising. So I pass just a string through thrift and then process it using JODA libraries?

Comment: i have edited the answer you can do something like that to store the timestamp.

Comment: I'll have to try it myself, but this JODA seems to provide features missing in thrift, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of some specific format preference. I usually use decimal encoded date representation, since it's quite compact and human-readable, like this: `20130325`

Comment: Hm, I like that representation. Just to make sure - is it an integer or a string?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Integer of cause. `i32` thrift data type.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a structure to represent you ThriftDate:

```
struct ThriftDate {
  1: i32 year;
  2: i32 month;
  3: i32 day;
}
```